# Why does the execution of latex/hide-show-all with hooks not work?

Tags: latex, hooks

I'm using AUCTeX, CDlatex and latex-extra to write LaTeX-files. When I access a file I'd want the contents of its sections to be hidden by default using the latex-extra<sup>1</sup> command `latex/hide-show-all`, so I tried to use hooks to execute it whenever the modes in question are loaded. I tried putting the following things into the `:config`-section of `(use-package tex)`:

```
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all 100)
  (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all 100)
  (add-hook 'latex-math-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all 100)
  (add-hook 'cdlatex-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all 100)
  (add-hook 'latex-extra-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all 100)
```

I've tried all these hooks and put them to 100 to see if any of them worked, but none do. However, if I run `latex/hide-show-all` immediately after opening a file, it works. I've also looked at the hooks as variables, and `latex/hide-show-all` is in them. Why don't the hooks work and how can I make them work?

Edit:
Following NickD's advice in the comments, I removed the other hooks and restarted Emacs using a small testing `use-package` config:

```
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex
  :init
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex-extra-mode)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all)  
  )
```

My `LaTeX-mode-hook`-variable value with this setup is

```
(preview-mode-setup latex/hide-show-all latex-extra-mode
                    citar-capf-setup)
```

But I also tried configurations where `latex/hide-show-all` was after `latex-extra-mode`. Still, it doesn't work. Is this a bug and if so, who should I send a bug report to?

---

<sup>1</sup>  The `latex-extra` package is available from MELPA or at  https://github.com/Malabarba/latex-extra.

Comment: You only need the first one. You don't need the last argument (the 100) at all (although it works with it as well). Check the value of the hook with `C-h v LaTeX-mode-hook` to make sure that the function has been added. Also make sure that you don't have the .tex file open already: the hook is only run when the file is opened. FWIW, this works for me.

Comment: Make sure that you delete the function from all the other hooks. It may be that you call the function twice (or four times) through different hooks (one major mode hook and one (or three) minor mode  hooks), ending up with no change at all.

Comment: Further, see `C-h f latex-mode` where it says: `This function has :override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’.

This is an :override advice, which means that ‘latex-mode’ isn’t
run at all, and the documentation below may be irrelevant.` This is the plain vanilla latex-mode and AUCTeX overrides it: it *never* gets run, so setting its hook is useless in any case if you use AUCTeX.

Comment: @NickD Following your advice I restarted Emacs with a testing configuration, but it still doesn't work. I put the details of the configuration and variable into the question. Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: I doubt it. As I said, it works for me (but I don't use `use-package`). With your testing configuration, if you open a .tex file what is the mode that it reports on the mode line? I get `fundamental` which indicates insufficient initialization to me, but I don't know much about `use-package`. I would skip the `use-package` and do the initialization by hand: `use-package` is convenient but it makes things difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is incomplete.

With the following init file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path  (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa/auctex-13.2.1/"))
(add-to-list 'load-path  (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa/latex-extra-20220817.5/"))

(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex
  :init
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex-extra-mode)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all)  
  :config
  (require 'latex-extra)
  )
```

and starting with `emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo.el` (where `foo.el` contains the code above), it works for me. You should make sure that the two paths added to `load-path` make sense on your system (you may be using different versions of the packages e.g.)

But again, I think you should walk before you run: learn how to do it by hand and then go back and try `use-package`. As I said, `use-package` is convenient but hides things under the covers, making it difficult to debug problems.

EDIT: Try putting the following into a new file `/tmp/foo2.el` and start with `emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo2.el`:

```el
(package-initialize)

(require 'tex)
(require 'latex-extra)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex-extra-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex/hide-show-all)
```

Then open a .tex file. If it doesn't work, does the `*Messages*` buffer contain *any* error messages? Also, switch to the `*scratch*` buffer and type the following two lines, ending each one with `C-j` so that they are evaluated: each should give a path:

```el
(locate-library "tex")
(locate-library "latex-extra")
```

Post the returned paths in a comment.

Comment: I just tried your `use-package`-config, but it still didn't work. I also tried taking the two `add-hook`-lines out of `use-package` and putting them directly into my init-file, but it also didn't work. I'm getting a message however when I restart Emacs (and only then): `Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘latex-extra-mode’`. This happens even if I put `require 'latex-extra` into my init before `use-package tex` is read. Could that be related? I could try not using `use-package tex` at all, but I don't know how to ensure `auctex` then (this is how they do it in the manual).

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the last part, but I tried now putting your code into its own init file and starting from there and it still doesn't work, though it sent no error messages and `latex/hide-show-all` is in the hook variable.

Comment: See the EDIT in the answer for a suggestion.

Comment: When I start with that init it says `Error loading autoloads: (void-function helm-make-source)`. I've used Helm some time ago, but I don't know how the init knows that since it doesn't contain any reference to it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `-Q` to start it? Emacs should not know anything about that. I think you need to clean up your installation: maybe start afresh.

Comment: What happens with just `emacs -Q`? Without any init file?

Comment: If I use only `-Q` it doesn't give an error. It has to be something about `package-initialize`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150200/discussion-between-nickd-and-alexander-praehauser).